# Not enough input arguments error

Tags: matlab, function, arguments

Error at line2.Error is not enough input arguments.Variable original is a image file.I stored it in current folder path.Why it is showing error?

```
 function blur = blurMetric(original)
 I = double(original);
 [y x] = size(I);

 Hv = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]/9;
 Hh = Hv';
 ....
 ....
 ....
 end
```

Comment: This is odd. Can you add the exact error message to your question, and maybe a sample `original` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: not enough input arguments at line number 2

Comment: original is image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB `double` will not work if `original` is a file name (regardless of whether it is on the path or not).  Also if you're have the right toolbox check out `im2double`.

Either from the command line:

```
original = imread(filename);
blur = blurMatrix(original);
```

Or put the file read into the function itself.